# JSON_PRETTY_PRINT not working as expected when Content-Type is HTML

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I'm receiving a JSON string dynamically, which looks like:

> { "post": [ { "id": "11", "body": "", "image": "images/rose.png", "stamp": "2013-11-04 14:50:11" } ] }

I'm trying to pretty-print this JSON string as follows:

```
{
    "post": [
        {
            "id": "11",
            "body": "",
            "image": "images/rose.png",
            "stamp": "2013-11-04 14:50:11"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I tried the following code (just for demonstration purposes):

```
<?php

$str = '{ "post": [ { "id": "11", "body": "", "image": "images\/rose.png", "stamp": "2013-11-04 14:50:11" } ] }';
$obj = json_decode($str);
echo json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

And it just outputs the unformatted JSON string:

> { "post": [ { "id": "11", "body": "", "image": "images/rose.png", "stamp": "2013-11-04 14:50:11" } ] }

But when I add the following line above my `json_encode()` statement, it works as expected.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

What could be causing this issue? Why is it not working when the `Content-Type` is `text/html`?

Answer (score 29):

`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` uses whitespace to format the JSON. When this is displayed as HTML the whitespace is ignored. If you want to keep the formatting then wrap the JSON in `<pre>` tags.

For example:

```
<?php

$str = '{ "post": [ { "id": "11", "body": "", "image": "images\/rose.png", "stamp": "2013-11-04 14:50:11" } ] }';
$obj = json_decode($str);
$json = json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

printf("<pre>%s</pre>", $json);
```

If you don't want to use `<pre>` tags then you can also use the CSS property, `white-space: pre` on whatever element the JSON is contained in.

Answer (score 6):

You use this header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```